# Laravel - Routes not working (Not found)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I have a working route as

```
Route::get('/{url}', 'Controller@view)->name('view')->where('url', '[\w\d\-]+(.*)');
```

This works perfectly and shows the page as below (just demo page):
[image: Demo Landing Page]

I have a link on this page to place a order and I want to create a route as

```
Route::get('/{url}/order', 'Controller@order)->name('order')->where('url', '[\w\d\-]+(.*)');
```

**View Blade**

```
<a href="{{ route('order', $product['url']) }}">Order Now</a>
```

**`php artisan route:list`**

```
|    | GET|HEAD | {slug}        | view   | App\Http\Controllers\Controller@view    | web   |
|    | GET|HEAD | {slug}/order  | order  | App\Http\Controllers\Controller@order   | web   |
```

Whenever I click on this link Laravel returns **Not Found Error**. What is issue? I restarted server & checked for Mod_rewrite. Everything is fine.

Comment: Switch the position of your 2 routes.``{slug}/order`` goes to ``{{slug}}`` because it fits the requirements. If you move the order above the regular slug it should work

Comment: @universal : Please show your value for *$product['url']*

Comment: @Taacoo solution worked!

Comment: Ill make it an answer, which you can accept if you want @universal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routes work from top to bottom. Laravel searches for anything that fits the given URL.

When using `{{slugs}}` or any other parameters it is key that you put the key with the widest range on the bottom of your routes.

Example:

```
Route::get('/{url}', 'Controller@index);
Route::get('/{url}/order', 'Controller@order);
```

With this setup. **ALL** the routes will go to your Controller@index method. Since your {{url}} catches everything

By switching the 2 your more strict route is met first before the url with a very broad requirements.

For more info check the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing)

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot ' in your code
Change your code

```
Route::get('/{url}/order', 'Controller@order)->name('order')->where('url', '[\w\d\-]+(.*)');
```

to

```
Route::get('/{url}/order', 'Controller@order')->name('order')->where('url', '[\w\d\-]+(.*)');
```